# first page open response like classplbuildpublish error

Tags: ios, iphone, ios7, ios5

This is the error I'm getting in console when I run the app.

> objc[4391]: Class PLBuildVersion is implemented in both
>   /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator.sdk/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AssetsLibraryServices.framework/AssetsLibraryServices
>   (0x112a1d910) and
>   /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator.sdk/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/PhotoLibraryServices.framework/PhotoLibraryServices
>   (0x112847210). One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.

Answer (score 0):

It's not a error,it print just when you test your APP on simulator. The reason is objc uses the same namespace  for your App,when class have the same name,The behavior of objc runtime is unpredictable. One possibility is that the class of any program will be loaded.